# Fullscreen functionality on saperate html button for highchart in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, fullscreen

Hello I have been looking for the a full screen functionality for chart in highchart. I have been referring the site and got this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-togglefullscreen/).

Here in javascript you can achieve this by simply handling click event like

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    chart.fullscreen.toggle();
});
```

I have tried the same thing for angular highcharts :

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.progressChart = Highcharts.chart(this.donutContainer.nativeElement, this.donutOptions, () => {
  /*
    Do things here after chart is drawn
  */
  }) 
}
onFullScreenClick(){
    this.progressChart.fullscreen.toggle()
}
```

But seems like this code is not working. I somewhere read you can also use `toggleFullScreen()`. But that is also not feasible.

Comment: Please provide a working example on stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

Fullscreen requires the fullscreen module, so if you did not imported and initialized that might be the reason.

```js
import HC_fullscreen from 'highcharts/modules/full-screen.js';
HC_fullscreen(Highcharts);
```

I have prepared a simple demo for you to show you the possible solution. I am using the official `highcharts-angular` wrapper there (I am encouraging you to check it out, it might make your life easier while working with highcharts in angular), but the solution made without the wrapper should be similar.

**Docs:** 
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

**Live demo:**
*(note - the fullscreen will not work inside the stack-blitz frame, but the following example will work in the real-life project)* 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-abnznx?file=src/app/app.component.ts